# ¿como pasar el valor de un input a un campo de fecha?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

hola tengo una pregunta como podría capturar el valor de un input y ese valor sumárselo como días a mi campo de fecha, ejemplo:

en mi input tengo un 2 y ese dos se lo sumo a la fecha, hoy es 10/06/2019 al sumar seria 12/06/2019

código para sumar fecha:

```
<?php
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$x = 1; 
$fecha = date("Y/m/d");
$fecha= date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$fecha + ". $x ." days")); $x dias
?>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fecha_inicio" id="fecha_inicio" 
      value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>">
```

input con el valor que quiero obtener:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="tiempo" id="tiempo">
```

ajax para enviar el dato:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enviardato").click(function(){
        var tiempo = $("#tiempo").val();       

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "scripts/sumar_fecha.php",
            data: {tiempo:tiempo},
            success: function(){
                alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

script en php para recibir la variable:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die(mysqli_error());
$tiempo=$_POST['tiempo'];


date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$tiempo; //dias a sumar
$fecha = date("Y/m/d");
$fecha= date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$fecha + ". $tiempo ." days")); //se suman los $x dias
?>
```

Comment: No entiendo, el valor que quieres ya esta en el input `fecha_inicio`, que quieres hacer con el input `tiempo`?

Comment: si el valor dentro del input previamente lo cargue ya esta en el input, y quiero obtener ese valor para pasarlo como variable y sumárselo a la fecha actual

Comment: Tendrias que usar Ajax o un `form` para pasar el valor del input y sumarlo.

Comment: no se podría obtener el valor,  ponerlo en una variable y pasarlo en el código que puse arriba, en lugar de la x=1 ahí colocar la variable que ya contiene el valor del input sin necesidad de un form nose con jquery o javascript?

Comment: Necesitas comunicar el cliente con el servidor de alguna manera.  No puedes simplemente "obtener el valor y ponerlo en una variable" del lado del servidor.

Comment: Para obtener el valor en PHP necesitas de un form para indicarle el método como obtendrás los valores por ejemplo `$_POST['tiempo']` y con esa variable ya sumas el tiempo a la fecha actual, así como lo indica @alanfcm.

Comment: edite mi pregunta en base a lo que me comentaron pero la verdad no se si este bien así y como mostraría la fecha con la suma en el input date ?

Comment: ya quedo resulto este tema muchas gracias por su ayuda si gustan marcarlo como cerrada